# How to summarily indicate that cited references fail to address a topic

Tags: citations, social-science

Academic citations are generally added because they explicitly support a statement. Occasionally however, it may be needed to cite references in support of a claim that they do *not* address a statement or topic at all. I seem to remember seeing *ab silentio* or *e silentio* appended to a citation call to indicate such a case, but can't find any example of, or reference to, this. Is my memory correct, in which case what is the correct usage and do you have an example of it? Otherwise, can some other type of citation-call prefix or suffix achieve this, short of a full explanatory sentence outside the citation call?

Comment: In such cases I don't exactly cite, but rather say something like "Previous work on foo, e.g. [12], does not address bar". Haven't seen shorthands such as what you're looking for; perhaps it's discipline-dependent.

Comment: In law there is the term [*sub silentio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sub_silentio). Could that be what you're looking for? Its meaning is a bit different to how, e.g., *ab silentio* etc. are used in *argumenta e silentio*, however.

Comment: I would find an explanatory sentence easier to understand, something like @einpoklum suggests. I would cite a number of recent reviews, however, rather than research work: the latter presumably describes just one approach of many. Also, be careful: on more than one occasion, I have discovered a whole body of literature on the topic from another field after spending some time learning to ask proper questions. Understanding a question is half an answer, or so they say.